# Multiply two values in a variable

Tags: php, replace

I have a string wich contains 2 values:

```
$total = '100x100';
```

It can also be

```
$total = '10x10';
```

I want to multiply the 2 values (100*100) and at the same time eliminate the 'x' so I can just have it to say '10000' for the first one or '100' for the second one.

I already eliminated the 'x':

```
$total = str_replace('x', '', $total);
```

What can I do now to multiply both?

Comment: `$data=explode('x', $total); $total=$data[0]*$data[1];` you may need to floatval() or intval() the numbers for the multiplication to work

Comment: Will the operation *always* be multiplication? Will the numbers *always* be the same?

Comment: Will it always just be "x" for multiply? Never "*" and never "+" or "-"?

Comment: Yeah, they will always be a _multiplication_ just *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$values = explode('x',$total);
array_product($values); // so even "10x40x20" is allowed and would work
```

Comment: :) yeah just saw your comment after posting my answer

Answer (score 1):

Explode the string into an array, then multiply those two array items together like this:

```
$total = array_product(explode('x', $string));
```

credit to Shikiryu